# Github Search doesn't include non-code files

Tags: github, parsing

I was looking and Palo Alto's Unit 42 Publishes, They have them on github like this one: https://github.com/pan-unit42/iocs/blob/master/venomrat_iocs.csv which contains the following domain: `baiwu123.e2.luyouxia.net`

But I can't find them using github search, for example if I search for the above domain I get nothing.

The same goes for `.md` files and not just `csv` files, or in general github ignores non-code files when doing search.

How can I still search all of those files for specific string without doing recursion?

Comment: why the `python` tag?

Comment: @buran I will implement this in python so I tagged the language cause it might be related or help others explain what's relevant to me

Comment: Right now, there is nothing python related. Post [mre] of your code, when you have one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're seeing, but when I search for the domain:

[image]

you can find the files you're looking for:

[image]

It also finds the same text in markdown files:

[image]

Comment: Hi, that's because it's available in txt files but you can't the instance found in the file I linked to above

Comment: That's the 2nd result in the screenshot...

Comment: sorry I mean md files

Comment: @dan it also finds the text in markdown. Are you sure the repository you're looking for isn't private and the token you're using to search has access to it?